# Radius of bands in single slit diffraction

Tags: optics, diffraction

We've been given the following situation:[image]

the cylindrical tube is of radius r and length l and is covered with an opaque disc having a small hole in the center on the left end and a point light source is placed on the right end. The inner surface of the tube is perfectly reflecting. A white screen is placed normally to the axis of the tube at a distance L from the end covered with the disc. 
 I know that single-slit diffraction is taking place here and we'll get a central bright spot surrounded by concentric bands. The problem wants us to find the radius of these bands. The solution given says that the radii of the bands are $$2n\frac{rL}{l}$$ where n = 1,2,3...

I'm not able to figure out how I can get here. I know how I can find the width of the central bright fringe but that's not what is being asked. Am I interpreting the problem wrong? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think is about diffraction (small it can be ignored) ..... is it possible that it is a glass tube where n is the index of refraction? .... then the spot size can be calculated based on angles.

Comment: oh. here's the actual problem and the given answer: https://i.imgur.com/Ldrfgdi.png
Please let me know what you think. Thanks! @PhysicsDave

Comment: I think maybe the problem is just based on simple observation/reflection .... the central spot is brightest and comes straight out .... the next ring is just what you would see after one reflection in the tube ..... the 2nd ring is after 2 reflections .... etc etc

Comment: Oh yes! It actually is about that. That small hole statement was really intimidating but I completely disregarded the reflecting surface of the tube. I was able to reach to the answer after that thought. Thanks! @PhysicsDave